# Returns the wrong UICollectionViewCell dimension - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Returns the cell item to the entire screen.

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "standardArticle", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "standardArticle")

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let customCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "standardArticle", for: indexPath)

    return customCell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
}
```

Image example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Did you set the delegate and dataSource of the collectionView? You need to set it to the view controller.

Comment: check to conform `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Comment: Also, could you use Debug View Hierarchy ? For instance, what's the content mode of the `UIImageView`?

Comment: Set the contentMode of imageView to scaleAspectFit.